# Conditional Iteration over a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which looks like:

```
    id              location    grain
0   BBG.XETR.AD.S       XETR    16.545
1   BBG.XLON.VB.S       XLON    6.2154
2   BBG.XLON.HF.S       XLON    NaN
3   BBG.XLON.RE.S       XLON    NaN
4   BBG.XLON.LL.S       XLON    NaN
5   BBG.XLON.AN.S       XLON    3.215
6   BBG.XLON.TR.S       XLON    NaN
7   BBG.XLON.VO.S       XLON    NaN
```

In reality this dataframe will be much larger.  I would like to iterate over this dataframe returning the `'grain'` value but I am only interested in the rows that have a value (not NaN) in the 'grain' column. So only returning as I iterate over the dataframe the following values:

```
16.545
6.2154
3.215
```

I can iterate over the dataframe using:

```
for staticidx, row in df.iterrows():
            value= row['grain']
```

But this returns a value for all rows including those with a NaN value.  Is there a way to either remove the NaN rows from the dataframe or skip the rows in the dataframe where grain equals NaN?

Many thanks

Comment: `df.grain[~pd.isnull(df.grain)]`?

Comment: alternatively you can do this: `df.ix[df.grain.notnull(), 'grain']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a list of columns in `dropna` on which to subset the data:

> subset : array-like
>       Labels along other axis to consider, e.g. if you are dropping rows
>       these would be a list of columns to include

```
>>> df.dropna(subset=['grain'])
              id location    grain
0  BBG.XETR.AD.S     XETR  16.5450
1  BBG.XLON.VB.S     XLON   6.2154
5  BBG.XLON.AN.S     XLON   3.2150
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
df[pd.notnull(df['grain'])]
```

Or this:

```
df['grain].dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's compare different methods (for 800K rows DF):

```
In [21]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**5, ignore_index=True)

In [22]: df.shape
Out[22]: (800000, 3)

In [23]: %timeit df.grain[~pd.isnull(df.grain)]
The slowest run took 5.33 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 17.1 ms per loop

In [24]: %timeit df.ix[df.grain.notnull(), 'grain']
10 loops, best of 3: 23.9 ms per loop

In [25]: %timeit df[pd.notnull(df['grain'])]
10 loops, best of 3: 35.9 ms per loop

In [26]: %timeit df.grain.ix[df.grain.notnull()]
100 loops, best of 3: 17.4 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit df.dropna(subset=['grain'])
10 loops, best of 3: 56.6 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit df.grain[df.grain.notnull()]
100 loops, best of 3: 17 ms per loop

In [30]: %timeit df['grain'].dropna()
100 loops, best of 3: 16.3 ms per loop
```